# a row of set sized divs don't align when their contents are different

Tags: css, html, position

I have 3 divs, all of a set height and width. The middel one has an extra line but it's still well within the 250px of the parent div. Yet it causes the two divs on either side to move down a little. Can someone explain why it's doing this so I can understand going forward?

```
<div id="eventListBox">

    <div class="eventListItemBox"> 
        <img src="./icons/bluedude.png" />
        <h1>Test Item 1</h1>
        <h2>Jan 6th, 2012</h2>
        <h2>5/11</h2>
    </div>


    <div class="eventListItemBox"> 
        <img src="./icons/cookies.png" />
        <h1>Very long title to cause wrap on line</h1>
        <h2>Jan 15th, 2012</h2>
        <h2>2/9</h2>
    </div>


    <div class="eventListItemBox"> 
        <img src="./icons/cookies.png" />
        <h1>Test item 3</h1>
        <h2>Jan 15th, 2012</h2>
        <h2>2/9</h2>
    </div>


</div>
```

CSS:

```
#eventListBox{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 75px;
    right: 75px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

.eventListItemBox{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

.eventListItemBox h1{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.eventListItemBox h2{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your boxes are not aligning evenly due to the fact that your divs are being displayed inline and because of this they need to be "told" how to vertically align themselves within a line-box, which you can do by using the `vertical-align` property. By default, all inline elements have a `vertical-align` value of `baseline`, which is why both your right and left divs are sticking to the bottom, so to fix this you need to tell them to stick to the top, to properly align all of your divs, you can do that by overwriting the default `vertical-align` value and set it to `top`, like so:

**CSS**

```
.eventListItemBox {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

You can find a more detailed explanation as to why this happens (with examples) on [this](http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/) article.